# Pair data type in C++ and FF SS operators

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and wanted to know what'd this declaration mean:

```
typedef pair<double,double> pairD;
pair<pairD, long> unknown;
```

what'd unknown be?

And more specifically, what'd these operators do:

```
unknown.FF.FF;
unknown.FF.SS;
```

Can you provide an example on what data one could initialize or fill in in such unknown data structure?

Thanks!

Comment: `unknown.FF.FF` The only operator I see is the dot operator.

Comment: @chris I mean the FF and SS indexes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unknown` is a `pair<pair<double, double>, long>`.

Impossible to guess what `FF` and `SS` mean with any certainty though. The obvious interpretation would be something about `FirstFirst` and `SecondSecond` -- but those don't fit with how they're being used (and while FirstFirst sort of makes sense, SecondSecond really doesn't, since unknown.second is a `long`, not a pair).

Having ruled that out, about all that's left is that they just stand for `first` and `second`, so `unknown.FF.SS` is equivalent to `unknown.first.second` and `unknown.FF.FF` is equivalent to `unknown.first.first`.

As to how to put data into an `unknown` like this, one possibility would be something like:

```
unknown x = std::make_pair(std::make_pair(1.0, 2.0), 3L);
```

Comment: @Jerry Coffin thanks makes sense now, FF is first and SS is second, got it from another code but now all makes sense

Answer (score 3):

In C++, `std::pair<F, S>` has two members:

```
F first;
S second;
```

Thus:

```
typedef pair<double,double> pairD;
pair<pairD, long> unknown;
```

expands to `pair<pair<double, double>, long>`. Given:

```
unknown = std::make_pair(std::make_pair(1.2, 2.4), 3);
```

then:

```
std::cout << unknown.first.first << std::endl;
std::cout << unknown.first.second << std::endl;
std::cout << unknown.second << std::endl;
```

prints:

```
1.2
2.4
3
```